# How I can fix Animation made frame issue/bug applying to Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want use spring animation on Text view but the animation changes the un-necessary thing for this view, which make some part get cut out because of this issue/bug. For understating I made to exact Text Views one with background Color and another without! as you see the spring animation should just play with position or offset of View, NOT with size of frame! **or it can be because of changing offset while position is the same.** which I strongly believe it is a bug. I can make my own custom spring animation works better than this, but I wanted know is there any way to solve the issue?

*PS: I found all kind of animation on Text have this issue!*

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stringForText: String = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        Button("add") { stringForText += "?"}.padding()
            
        Text(stringForText).font(.largeTitle).bold().padding().animation(.spring(response: 1, dampingFraction: 0.01, blendDuration: 1))
            
        Text(stringForText).font(.largeTitle).bold().background(Color.yellow).padding().animation(.spring(response: 1, dampingFraction: 0.01, blendDuration: 1))
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *you see the spring animation should just play with position or offset of View* - this assumption is incorrect. Implicit animation is applied to all animatable properties. In the consider case the are position and size (ie. actually frame) and they are animated as expected from smaller rect to bigger rect (with spring). Content, ie internal text, is not animatable. And from your post it is not clear what do you want actually to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Modifiers in SwiftUI are affected by order. Therefore, having the .animation modifier **after** all other modifiers means that SwiftUI will try to animate **all** (animatable) modifiers such as the .padding modifier (which is indeed animatable).

It is still unclear what the intended behavior is, however, by applying the solution mentioned above, the yellow background size remains untouched due to its padding being not animated.

Fixing padding change when using .animation:

[image]